# I can't make my texturing using GL_REPEAT to work on my Android Galaxy Tab 10.1 but it works on my phone and emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hi I am new in Android and OpenGLES development. I am trying to develop a simple Android game using OpenGL. The background image of my game is a tiling where I want to use the texture mapping wrap as `GL_REPEAT`. It is working fine in my Samsung Galaxy S and with the emulator for the platform 3.0. The problem is with my Samsung 10.1 Galaxy Tab where I cant get it to repeat the texture. It is always using the texture clamp to edge. I have found a texturing tutorial and when I modify the texture mapping and wrap parameters for this tutorial the texture is repeated as expected so I know that it is not a tablet bug in the tablet. The question is what is wrong in my code that is only being a problem for the tablet?

I am doing all texture setup in my a class that implements `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. Is this a problem?

```
package com.droidev.games.bubbilliards;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

import android.util.Log;

public class BBGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private BBGame game;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private float ratio_w_h;
    private ShortBuffer indicesBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer backgroundVertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer backgroundTextureBuffer;

    private Context context;
    private BBGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    private int ball_textures[];
    private int hole_open_textures[];
    private int hole_closed_textures[];
    private int background_textures[];
    private float length;

    private boolean texture_set;
    private Bitmap green_ball;
    private Bitmap orange_ball;
    private Bitmap purple_ball; 
    private Bitmap green_hole_open;
    private Bitmap orange_hole_open;
    private Bitmap purple_hole_open;
    private Bitmap green_hole_closed;
    private Bitmap orange_hole_closed;
    private Bitmap purple_hole_closed;
    private Bitmap background;



    public BBGLRenderer(Context context_, BBGLSurfaceView sv){
        super();
        context = context_; 
        glSurfaceView = sv;
        game = new BBGame(sv);
        texture_set = false;
    }



    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config){



        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        // reading images from resources        
        green_ball         = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.green_ball);
        orange_ball        = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.orange_ball);
        purple_ball        = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.purple_ball);

        green_hole_open    = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.green_hole_open);
        orange_hole_open   = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.orange_hole_open);
        purple_hole_open   = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.purple_hole_open);

        green_hole_closed  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.green_hole_closed);
        orange_hole_closed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.orange_hole_closed);
        purple_hole_closed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.purple_hole_closed);

        background         = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.tile);

        // creating textures IDS
        int num_colors = BBColor.values().length;

        ball_textures        = new int[num_colors];
        hole_open_textures   = new int[num_colors];
        hole_closed_textures = new int[num_colors];
        background_textures  = new int[1];

        gl.glGenTextures(num_colors, ball_textures       , 0);


        // balls
        initializeTexture(gl, green_ball ,        ball_textures,        (int)BBColor.GREEN.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, orange_ball,        ball_textures,        (int)BBColor.ORANGE.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, purple_ball,        ball_textures,        (int)BBColor.PURPLE.ordinal());

        gl.glGenTextures(num_colors, hole_open_textures  , 0);

        // holes open
        initializeTexture(gl, green_hole_open ,   hole_open_textures,   (int)BBColor.GREEN.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, orange_hole_open,   hole_open_textures,   (int)BBColor.ORANGE.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, purple_hole_open,   hole_open_textures,   (int)BBColor.PURPLE.ordinal());

        gl.glGenTextures(num_colors, hole_closed_textures, 0);

        // holes closed
        initializeTexture(gl, green_hole_closed,  hole_closed_textures, (int)BBColor.GREEN.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, orange_hole_closed, hole_closed_textures, (int)BBColor.ORANGE.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, purple_hole_closed, hole_closed_textures, (int)BBColor.PURPLE.ordinal());

        gl.glGenTextures(1         , background_textures , 0);      
        initializeTexture(gl, background, background_textures, 0);


//      initializeBuffers();

    }

    public void initializeTextures(GL10 gl){
        int num_colors = BBColor.values().length;
        gl.glGenTextures(num_colors, ball_textures       , 0);
        gl.glGenTextures(num_colors, hole_open_textures  , 0);
        gl.glGenTextures(num_colors, hole_closed_textures, 0);
        gl.glGenTextures(1         , background_textures , 0);

        // balls
        initializeTexture(gl, green_ball ,        ball_textures,        (int)BBColor.GREEN.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, orange_ball,        ball_textures,        (int)BBColor.ORANGE.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, purple_ball,        ball_textures,        (int)BBColor.PURPLE.ordinal());
        // holes open
        initializeTexture(gl, green_hole_open ,   hole_open_textures,   (int)BBColor.GREEN.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, orange_hole_open,   hole_open_textures,   (int)BBColor.ORANGE.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, purple_hole_open,   hole_open_textures,   (int)BBColor.PURPLE.ordinal());
        // holes closed
        initializeTexture(gl, green_hole_closed,  hole_closed_textures, (int)BBColor.GREEN.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, orange_hole_closed, hole_closed_textures, (int)BBColor.ORANGE.ordinal());
        initializeTexture(gl, purple_hole_closed, hole_closed_textures, (int)BBColor.PURPLE.ordinal());

        initializeTexture(gl, background, background_textures, 0);
        texture_set = true;
    }

    public void initializeTexture(GL10 gl, Bitmap bmp, int textures[], int color){
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[color]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

//      gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_, pixels)
    }

    public void initializeBuffers(int w, int h){

        length = Math.min(ratio_w_h/(float)game.getWidth(), 1.0f/(float)game.getHeight());
        // Vertices Position //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        float vertices[] = {0.0f  , 0.0f  , 0.0f,
                            length, 0.0f  , 0.0f,                           
                            0.0f  , length, 0.0f,
                            length, length, 0.0f};

        ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        vertexBuffer = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // indices ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        short[] indices = new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

        ByteBuffer indicesByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        indicesByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indicesBuffer = indicesByteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
        indicesBuffer.put(indices);
        indicesBuffer.position(0);

        // Texture Coords /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        float coords[] = {0.0f, 1.0f,
                  1.0f, 1.0f,                
                  0.0f, 0.0f,
                  1.0f, 0.0f};

        ByteBuffer textureByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coords.length * 4);
        textureByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        textureBuffer = textureByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(coords);
        textureBuffer.position(0);


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Vertices Position //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        float verticesBackground[] = {0.0f     , 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                      game.getWidth()*length, 0.0f, 0.0f,                                     
                                      0.0f     , game.getHeight()*length, 0.0f,
                                      game.getWidth()*length, game.getHeight()*length, 0.0f};

        ByteBuffer backgroundVertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(verticesBackground.length * 4);
        backgroundVertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        backgroundVertexBuffer = backgroundVertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        backgroundVertexBuffer.put(verticesBackground);
        backgroundVertexBuffer.position(0);

        // Texture Coords /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        float coordsBackground[] = {0.0f, game.getHeight(),
                                    game.getWidth(), game.getHeight(),
                                    0.0f, 0.0f,
                                    game.getWidth(), 0.0f};

        ByteBuffer backgroundTextureByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coordsBackground.length * 4);
        backgroundTextureByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        backgroundTextureBuffer = backgroundTextureByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        backgroundTextureBuffer.put(coordsBackground);
        backgroundTextureBuffer.position(0);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




        game.setResolution(w, h);
        game.setRatio_W_H(ratio_w_h);
        game.setSquareLength(length);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h){
        width = w;
        height = h;
        ratio_w_h = (float)width/(float)height;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0.0f, ratio_w_h*1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        initializeBuffers(w, h);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, backgroundTextureBuffer);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, background_textures[0]);
        //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
//      if(!texture_set){
//          initializeTextures(gl);
//          initializeBuffers(width, height);
//      }
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);       
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, backgroundVertexBuffer);





//      gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
//      gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
//      gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
//      gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


//      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        for(BBHole h: game.getHoles()){
            gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(h.getX()*length, h.getY()*length, 0.0f);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, (h.isOpen())?hole_open_textures[h.getColor().ordinal()]:hole_closed_textures[h.getColor().ordinal()]);
//          gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);    
            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        }


        for(BBBubble b: game.getBubbles()){
            synchronized (b) {
                gl.glPushMatrix();
                gl.glTranslatef(b.getX()*length+b.getTx(), b.getY()*length+b.getTy(), 0.0f);
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ball_textures[b.getColor().ordinal()]);
//              gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);        
                gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
                gl.glPopMatrix();
                b.notifyAll();
            }
        }




//      gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//      gl.glFlush();
//      Log.i("GL_ERROR = ", Integer.toString( gl.glGetError()));
        glSurfaceView.setDirty(false);
    }

    public BBGame getGame(){
        return game;
    }
}
```

So I basically have an `Activity` a class that extends the `GLSurfaceView`, a class presented above that implements the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` and a class that have the game rules, etc.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think GL_REPEAT only works with POT (power of two) textures and your drawable-xyz probably got scaled up or down to a non-POT size.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution for my problem but it does not make sense for me. The project that was created in eclipse had in the res folder only the folders drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi but not a drawable folder such as in the tutorial I have mentioned before.

So the solution was to create this "drawable" folder and put the image there. Then GL_REPEAT "magically" worked for the galaxy tab. I wasted 2 days because of this folder problem :(.

I am curious if it makes sense or not and if I should put all my textures inside these drawable folder always.